# Extract images from Excel sheet with Delphi

Tags: excel, image, delphi, extract

I have a Excel sheet and in several cells i have a picture in the upper left corner of the cell.  These pictures behave as if they are "attached" to a given cell, in that if I change the boundaries of a cell, its picture moves with it.

How can I extract these pictures and save them to files using Delphi?

Comment: Hi Frans, welcome. You're more likely to get answers that are valuable to you (and others) when you ask a more specific question. There are many examples on working with Excel from Delphi online (https://www.google.com/search?q=read+excel+delphi&oq=read+excel+delphi). Try that, and feel free to come back to ask a question when you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Hello Wouter, I know there are many examples but always writing tekst and image to Excel and reading text from Excel but I cannot find a delphi example that loads a ppicture attached to cells in Excel.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't have a ready-to-use answer for you in my back pocket. There are probably hundreds of people on this site who -could- help you with this, but if you ask your question the wrong way, chances are small that anyone will take the effort to help you. I'm just trying to help you to help yourself on this site because I see that you're new here. Otherwise I would just skip this question myself too. Nobody will to take you by the hand from start to end, so use the short attention that you'll receive for stuff that you really cannot figure out yourself.

Comment: Last hint: if you have excel installed, you can instantiate it as a com object. If i remember correctly, the worksheet contains a `pictures` property that you could iterate. Maybe something to look into.

Comment: If I recall, images aren't necessarily inside of a cell, but positioned in the overall worksheet.

Comment: What is it **exactly** that you want to do with a picture in a worksheet?

Comment: Images can be added/embedded in Excel files at least in three different ways. 1) Embedded in a comment as @MartynA demonstrated. 2) Through `Insert - Picture` menu or 3) through `Insert - Object`. I haven't investigated, but I suspect the images are stored in different ways in an Excel file depending on how they were added. If you don't know, and can't ask, how they were added, your need to do some investigation on your own to clarify.

Comment: What happens when you click on an image? Do handles appear in the corners? If not, try to remove the Worksheet and/or Workbook protection (Review - protection), and try again. If you get the handles, do you also get a rotation handle? Can you now copy (right-click, copy) and paste into e.g. Windows Paint? Please add answers to these question as an edit of your question, and also indicate which Excel version and which Delphi version you use.

Answer (score 2):

**Update #4**  The OP belatedly provided instructions to prepare an example of the picture he's been trying to extract:

> 1) Go to nbbclubsites.nl/club/8000/uitslagen 2) Click on "TKDmm, ronde 1 [1]" 3) Click on -14- 13/3 4) Clik on "B.C. Den Dungen-1" 5) Select de 4 and hearts symbol 6) Copy Ctrl+C 7) Open Excel and select cell (1,1) 8) Past Ctrl+V In the cell you see 4 in the cell and the heart symbol locked left upper corner

I did this and the hearts symbol pasted into my worksheet without any problem.  After doing that, the `SavePicture` method in item `1 Insert Picture` correctly extracts and saves the hearts symbol to disk as a .Jpg file. Doh!

**Update #3**  A problem with answering this question has been that there is no
information about how the pictures in the OP's spreadsheet have been inserted.  So far,
three different methods have been identified namely:

- Using Insert - Picture from Excel's Insert Tab
- Using Insert - Object from Excel's Insert Tab
- Using Insert Comment from the selected cell's context menu

Below I show code examples for each of these methods.

**1.  Insert - Picture**

```
procedure TForm1.InsertPicture;
begin
  Worksheet.Pictures.Insert('C:\Users\ma\Pictures\photo-2.JPG');
end;

procedure TForm1.SavePicture;
var
  Picture : OleVariant;
begin
  Picture := Worksheet.Pictures[1];
  Picture.Select;
  Picture.Copy;
  SaveClipboard;
end;
```

**2.  Insert - Object**

```
procedure TForm1.InsertAsObject;
begin
  WorkSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:='C:\Users\ma\Pictures\wall.bmp', Link :=False,
    DisplayAsIcon:=False).Select;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveObjectBmp;
var
  Shape : OleVariant;
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(WorkSheet.OleObjects.Count);
  WorkSheet.OLEObjects[1].Select;
  WorkSheet.OLEObjects[1].CopyPicture;
  Shape := WorkSheet.OLEObjects[1].ShapeRange.Item(1);
  Shape.CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlBitMap);
  SaveClipboard;
end;
```

**3.  Insert as cell comment**

```
procedure TForm1.InsertCommentPicture;
var
  Cell,
  Comment : OleVariant;
begin
  Cell := WorkSheet.Cells.Range['b2', 'b2'];
  Comment := Cell.AddComment;
  Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture('C:\Users\ma\Pictures\photo-2.JPG');
  Comment.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveCommentPicture;
var
  Cell,
  Comment,
  Shape,
  Picture : OleVariant;
begin
  Cell := WorkSheet.Cells.Range['B2', 'B2'];
  Comment := Cell.Comment;
  Comment.Visible := True;

  Shape := Comment.Shape;
  Shape.CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlBitMap);
  SaveClipBoard;
end;
```

The SaveClipBoard method and FormCreate method are shown below.  `Excel`, `WorkBook`
and `WorkSheet` are all OleVariant members of the form.

```
procedure TForm1.SaveClipboard;
// With thanks to the author of http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=46877
var
  myBitmap: TBitmap;
  myJpegImg: TJpegImage;
  SaveFileName: string;
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(Clipboard.FormatCount)  + ':' + IntToStr(Clipboard.Formats[0]);
  SaveFileName := ExtractFilePath(FileName) + 'Saved.Jpg';
  myBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  myJpegImg := TJpegImage.Create;
  try
    if Clipboard.HasFormat(cf_Bitmap) then
      begin
        myBitmap.Assign(clipboard);
        myJpegImg.Assign(myBitmap);
        myJpegImg.SaveToFile(SaveFileName);
      end
    else
      ShowMessage('No graphic on the clipboard');
  finally
    myBitmap.FreeImage;
    myJpegImg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Visible := True;
  FileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'PictureBook.Xlsx';
  WorkBook := Excel.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
  WorkSheet := WorkBook.ActiveSheet;
end;
```

Comment: The examples below all use the other way around. Saving picture to Excel cell has many examples. Mostly vba examples.The message above : Pictures aren't tied to specific worksheet cells" is not true for the excel sheet i have. The picture stays attached to the left upper corner of the cell. If i copy the cell to another cell the image goes with it. I need the delphi source that extracts this image from the cell. Not save the image to a cell. Also with vba there is no example to my nolidge that extract the picture. I could send a excel example but I see I cannot attache a file.

Comment: Hmm.  Your said " have a picture **in** the upper left corner of the cell", not "attached to"  so you need to re-word your q otherwise someone else may waste their time answering it, as well as me.  How do you know the picture is "attached to" a specific cell?  What behaviour suugests that it is?

Comment: I think the picture is attached to a cell because if i resize the cell or copy the cell the picture stays visible in the left upper corner all the time. With attach i mean i cannot add a attachment to show what i mean

Comment: I did not attach the picture because if i did i would have the picture extracted. I receive Excel sheets with pictures attached in many cells

Comment: I did some research and I found out that the right expression must be: "The picture is LOCKED to the excel cell" So I want to save those locked images with Delphi code.

Comment: I tried your code, but the comment (with the image) doesn't stay foot in the top-left corner of the cell. Instead it has this arrow to the top-right corner of the cell, which grows/shrinks when the columns to the left or rows above are resized. The comment box however doesn't move. I think the images are added either through `Insert-Picture` or `Insert-Object`.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, @TomBrunberg.  I'm trying the Insert-Object method right now, but so far it's resting my attempts to extract the inserted image.  Later ...

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  I've got extracting the image working now, see update #2 in my answer.  Thanks fr the suggestion.  If this still doesn't satisfy the OP, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Frans:  Try update #2.  Does the inserted picture resemble yours, in term of appearance and behaviour?  It would help if you added a screenshot to your q ...

Comment: I can show how to reproduce my problem.
1) Go to https://www.nbbclubsites.nl/club/8000/uitslagen
2) Click on "TKDmm, ronde 1 [1]"
3) Click on -14-
                 13/3
4) Clik on "B.C. Den Dungen-1"
5) Select de 4 and hearts symbol 
6) Copy Ctrl+C
7) Open Excel and select cell (1,1)
8) Past Ctrl+V
In the cell you see 4 in the cell and the heart symbol locked left upper corner
Problem:
I want to extract the heart symbol and save to file using Delphi.

Comment: Ok, I inserted the 4 and hearts symbol in my spreadsheet as you described.  If I then run the `SavePicture` method in item 1 of my updated (version #3) answer, it correctly saves the image to disk, so I'm a bit surprised you said it didn't work.  Note that it gets saved in the executable's directory - perhaps you have been looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You wrote:"I did this and the hearts symbol pasted into my worksheet without any problem. After doing that, the SavePicture method in item 1 Insert Picture correctly extracts and saves the hearts symbol to disk as a .Jpg file. Doh!"

Comment: Of course I can do this but that is not the problem. Imagine you have a Excel sheet with 100000 cells and in most, not all of the cells are symbols like the heart symbol in my example. I can not copy and past thru all those cells because it takes to much time. I want Delphi to go to all those 100000 cell and extract/save the pictures to files. I hope this gives more information.

Comment: So, you are saying that you don't actually have a copy of the spreadsheet shown on the web page????

Comment: Please answer my question.  If the answer is that you don't have the spreadsheet and can only access it through the web page, getting the images requires a completely different approach that the one here.

Comment: I copy the the sheet from the website and then paste it to Excel. I want to replace the hearts, spades etc. symbols with H, S etc. because I can not calculate with those symbols. A heart symbol in the cell with +3 I want to repace with H+3 as a text in the cell. So I first have to exctract the symbols in the sheet. If I now the filesize of the 4 symbols I can replace them with H,S,D,C. This was the ultimate goal.

Comment: I really do wish you would make the effort to explain things clearly; your drip-feed of information wastes so much time!  Do you mean that you copy the webpage into Excel using Select, Ctrl-c and then Ctrl-V in Excel (which only pastes the BMP in the blue strip at the top when I try it), or that you download an Excel workbook.  Anyway, I'm not doing any more on this Q&A until you provide some clear and unambiguous information.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Martyn. Sorry I can not explain it on a better way.

Comment: I leave it for now. Thanks

Comment: For now, just answer the question I just asked:  Do you mean that you copy the webpage into Excel using Select, Ctrl-c and then Ctrl-V in Excel (which only pastes the BMP in the blue strip at the top when I try it), or that you download an Excel workbook.

Comment: I copy the webpage(s) from the website with Ctrl+C. Then I copy this to a blank sheet in Excel. I get the same result in de Excelsheet as on the website except that the card symbols move to the upper left corner of each cell.

Comment: I want to have a Delphi app that looks to each cell if there is a symbol (bmp/pic) in the left upper corner. If so save the picture. Example if there is a picture in cell (123,123)  I want to save it as 'R123C123'  etc. When finished searching each cell of the sheet. I look at the saved symbols and replace each symbol with H(earts), S(pades), D(iamonds) or C(lubs). At last I replace each cell in the Excel sheet that contains the symbol with S,H,D or C and delete the picture in the cell (if possible but not required)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but hopefully this is usefull for someone coming here with the same question: how can I get the cell that an image is attached to and how can I save that image.
After long research I found that pictures are shapes on a sheet and that the picture has "topleftcell.address" which is the cell that the image is linked to.Shown as "$B$4"

Code for saving that image is in the answers given.

```
  for i := 1 to sheet.Shapes.Count do
  begin
    picture := Sheet.Pictures(Pictures(i, lcid);
    test := picture.topleftcell.address;
    picture.select;
    picture.Copy;
  end;
```